# Do protestants believe that the New Testament is the final covenant?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, protestantism, new-testament, covenants

Do Protestants believe that the New Testament is the final covenant/testament? For example, many branches which built off Christianity believe the Bible is not complete and requires another revelation/modification from Jesus Christ (i.e. Mormonism, JW's)

If so, what are the arguments / biblical basis used to support this view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Article VI of the Articles of Religion of the Church of England, which is accepted by most of the Anglican Communion, provides in part,  that

> HOLY Scripture containeth all things necessary to salvation: so that whatsoever is not read therein, nor may be proved thereby, is not to be required of any man, that it should be believed as an article of the Faith, or be thought requisite or necessary to salvation. ...

Lutherans hold to the same viewpoint.

Comment: This is a bit sparse, but it's on the right track. Pretty much every major Protestant confession of faith ever says something along these lines. It might be worth expanding this answer to show that this isn't just a few samples. Also as I mention in [this comment](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55059/do-protestants-believe-that-the-new-testament-is-the-final-covenant#comment151534_55059) noting the difference between groups that this holds true for (reformers, i.e. Protestants) vs. ones it does not (reconstructionists, i.e. LDS, SDA, JW, etc.) might be useful.

Comment: @Caleb, while I  understand that all Christians that self-identify as protestant agree with what I cite from the Articles of Religion from the Church of England,  I only feel qualified to answer based on Lutherans and Anglicans,  as these are the groups with which I have familiarity. The question also involves a different one, who gets to decide who is, and who is not a Protestant. Some who characterize themselves in that way do not agree that others are properly characterized that way. My own thoughts on the matter are that those who believe the Bible is incomplete are not protestants.

Answer (score 1):

Revelation 22 says this:

> 18 I warn everyone who hears the words of the prophecy of this scroll:
>   If anyone adds anything to them, God will add to that person the
>   plagues described in this scroll. 19 And if anyone takes words away
>   from this scroll of prophecy, God will take away from that person any
>   share in the tree of life and in the Holy City, which are described in
>   this scroll.

The context makes it clear that this warning only applies to the book of Revelation itself. However, since the book of Revelation occurs last in most Christian Bibles, and the Apostle John was the last of the Apostles to die and the words and writing of the Apostles are given greater weight than those of other believers, it is commonly assumed by many Christians that this prohibition applies to the whole Bible: no more additions. This has the force, not of doctrine, but of a strong impression that most Christians accept, or at least give credence to.